# Length of passed values is 3, index implies 8

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am testing on the 3 factors that will affect the Grain Radius. Where the Grain Radius is the value Y. And Power Temperature, Extrusion Rate, and Die Temperature are the 3 factors that will affect Y.

Now, I am trying to find the sloop for these but have some errors here.

Data File:

```
    Grain Radius    Power Temperature (X1)  Extrusion Rate (X2) Die Temperature (X3)
0   82  150 12  220
1   93  190 12  220
2   114 150 24  220
3   124 150 12  250
4   111 190 24  220
5   129 190 12  250
6   157 150 24  250
7   164 190 24  250
```

my code is below:

```
data = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx')
data.columns = ['grain_size','power_temp','extrusion_rate','die_temp']
Y = data['grain_size']
X = data.iloc[:,1:]
X_Centered = X-X.mean()
from numpy.linalg import inv
XX_inv = inv(np.matmul(X_Centered.values.T,X_Centered.values))
XX_inv_X = np.matmul(XX_inv,X_Centered.values.T)
np.matmul(XX_inv_X,Y)
```

My error:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-dc871b000aea> in <module>
      2 XX_inv = inv(np.matmul(X_Centered.values.T,X_Centered.values))
      3 XX_inv_X = np.matmul(XX_inv,X_Centered.values.T)
----> 4 np.matmul(XX_inv_X,Y)

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __array_wrap__(self, result, context)
    733         """
    734         return self._constructor(result, index=self.index,
--> 735                                  copy=False).__finalize__(self)
    736 
    737     def __array_prepare__(self, result, context=None):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    247                             'Length of passed values is {val}, '
    248                             'index implies {ind}'
--> 249                             .format(val=len(data), ind=len(index)))
    250                 except TypeError:
    251                     pass

ValueError: Length of passed values is 3, index implies 8
```

I have tried to used np.matmul(XX_inv_X.T,Y) for the last line but it is not working as well.

Expected output:

```
array([0.125     , 2.45833333, 1.45      ])
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? Not just the last line, but the lines before it too?

Comment: I've executed your code and my output is: `array([0.125     , 2.45833333, 1.45      ])`.
Give us an example of the output you desire.

Comment: @CarloAlberto I am not sure why I have an error. But the expected output is the same as yours

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that there might be something wrong with the dataframe, maybe you could print it  and show us the output? Also, if you try `np.matmul(XX_inv_X.T,Y)` does it give you the same error?

Comment: @CarloAlberto the error is different for np.matmul(XX_inv_X.T,Y). It shows ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 8 is different from 3)

Comment: when you execute `np.matmul(XX_inv_X,Y)` are you setting it equal to something? Like `van_name = np.matmul(XX_inv_X,Y)`

Comment: @CarloAlberto No, I didn't set it equal to anything, even I try to set it, it shows the same error. Would it be the package I use?